# Store Array Values over multiple triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a task that need to push data in a array multiple times , this takes more than 15 mins so I need to create trigger after 5 mins each time. Problem is after a new trigger my array reset empty . I'm doing like this :

```
    var x = [] ;

function main () {
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var start = parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty('start'));

for ( var i = start ; i<= 1000; i++) {

var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      if (currentTime - startTime >= 250000)
      { 
        scriptProperties.setProperty('start',i);
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('main')
                .timeBased()
                .after(1000)
                .create();
      } 
      else {
x.push(i); // this takes more than 15 mins for example, so It need about 3 trigger to complete
}
} 
Logger.log('return values of array x ' + x); // it's not return from 0-1000 as I want , it's just return values that pushed in the most recent trigger, ex : from 900-1000
}
```

Comment: Is this a standalone script? Doesn't it get saved onto the properties? Can you detail more about it?

Comment: sorry I'm very newbie to this, I don't really understand your question . and yes , it's not saved onto the properties. Everytime time the new trigger launch, x array turn into empty. As I understand, if I declare variable globally, when trigger run main function, it's not affect on data which are pushed into x array before, but it seems not to work like that

Comment: The problem is that every time you call the function `var x = []` and all the other globals get initialized.  In fact anytime you call any function.  You might be better to show us what you are trying to do and perhaps we can suggest a quicker way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @Cooper what I'm trying to do is that I want to store value that I get from for loop in an array, and I can use that array in the future, regardless of how many loops passed, my array is not initialized again :( .

Comment: Use properties service of cache service.  That's where your storing start so why not everything else

Comment: Did you solve it with the properties service? Can you update on that?

Comment: Yes , I solved it , stringify array and save it in properties, use Json.parse when you get it out

Answer (score 0):

The solution is from the asking user and posted on the comments:

> Yes , I solved it , stringify array and save it in properties, use Json.parse when you get it out